# Lua WinAPI - Read cell from Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, winapi, lua

I am trying to read values from cells of a running [Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/) 2007 document.  I am using the [WinAPI extension](https://github.com/stevedonovan/winapi) for [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).  I am currently running on a Windows XP computer (if that matters, but it seems the WinAPI works from XP on.

This is my Excel document:

[image: Excel]

This is my Lua code:

```
require 'winapi'

w = winapi.find_window_match('Book1') -- Specify the name of the window

w:show() -- Set the visability

w:set_foreground() -- Bring this window to the foreground

handle = w:get_handle() -- Get window handle

t = {} -- Create a table

w:enum_children(function(w) table.insert(t,w) end) -- Enumerate all children

for k,v in pairs(t) do -- Print out all pairs in the table
    print("",k,"=",v)
end
```

This is my Lua code output:

[image: code output]

Does anyone know how I recursively should enumerate in order to find each Cell?  Or is there a better way to go about this?  The text I want is the "1234".  I have not done much Windows programming since I prefer Unix, but it seems like I am on the right track.  I just don't know how to progress from here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that Excel uses a window for each and every cell in the spreadsheet, so trying to get to the cell by navigating the window hierarchy is likely a dead end.

If possible, I'd recommend exporting the data to a common file type, like comma-separated values, and making your program parse that.

Alternatively, you can read about [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is how things like screen readers can access the data in a Windows application's UI.  I've never done that, but it looks like it might be a lot of work.  Nevertheless, I believe it's the most robust, supported method for trying to get data out of a Windows application via its user interface.